# Error when running the command:minikube dashboard

Tags: linux, docker, http, kubernetes, minikube

When I successfully run command 'minikube start',after that I ran the 'minikube dashborad' command ,but I got the error `"Exiting due to SVC_URL_TIMEOUT: http:///api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/http:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/ is not accessible: checkURL: Get "http:///api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/http:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/": http: no Host in request URL"`

Could you help me solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe need to use `--port` tag to set a specific port, I run command `minikube dash board --port 0` to use a random port; then i successfully open the dashboard!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the download of the dashboard image was very slow (it waits after arround 12MB for some seconds).
So I step into the minikube docker

```
minikube ssh
```

pulled the image manually:

```
 docker pull docker.io/kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.7.0@sha256:2e500d29e9d5f4a086b908eb8dfe7ecac57d2ab09d65b24f588b1d449841ef93
```

after that the dashboard works.

The name of the image which should be pulled I got from the logs.

```
kubectl describe pod  --namespace kubernetes-dashboard <name of the pod>
```

output:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                    From     Message
  ----     ------   ----                   ----     -------
  Warning  Failed   13m (x16 over 88m)     kubelet  Failed to pull image "docker.io/kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.7.0@sha256:2e500d29e9d5f4a086b908eb8dfe7ecac57d2ab09d65b24f588b1d449841ef93": rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
  Normal   BackOff  9m52s (x268 over 88m)  kubelet  Back-off pulling image "docker.io/kubernetesui/dashboard:v2.7.0@sha256:2e500d29e9d5f4a086b908eb8dfe7ecac57d2ab09d65b24f588b1d449841ef93"
```